# What is the correct datetime-cast for a QueryType in EFCore?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, view, ef-core-2.1

I have a view in my database I want to read with EF Core.

The data I read with my view is a int column which I can convert into the correct date by this SQL statement:

```
 CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEADD(MI, wf_activate, '1899-30-12'), 101) + ' ' + 
     CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEADD(MI, wf_activate, '1899-30-12'), 110) AS Start
```

This will convert the data correctly into this:

```
12/17/2018 12-17-2018
```

Now I want to access my view with EF Core 2.1 with this model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Basis data from an ELO workflow.
/// </summary>
public class WorkflowStrangeUsersModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the workflow start date.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
```

and this context:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Query<WorkflowStrangeUsersModel>().ToView("INTRANET_WorkflowsStrangeUsers");
    }
```

Which works with strings and int and so on, but in this case the datetime throws an error:

> An exception occurred while reading a database value for property 'WorkflowStrangeUsersModel.Start'. The expected type was 'System.DateTime' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'.

So I assume that my convert into 101 / 110 (usa date format) is wrong. I tried the local format as well (German) and the default (0) but same error.

Any idea?

Comment: Store dates as a date in your database, it will make your life easier

Comment: Its a database I dont have access to. I just can store my views and do things there.

Comment: 1 - Your TSQL should not return a string but a DateTime, 2- `12/17/2018 12-17-2018` is in no way a correct date. I usually check the TSQL formats in [CAST and CONVERT doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: If you can change your VIEW definition, change it into the following: `convert(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEADD(MI, wf_activate, '18991230'), 101))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can retrieve the date as an int and then convert it to a Datetime using C#. You can use 2 properties for this, StartInt and StartDate (that one would be read only)

Comment: But when I have a DTO for that view which is bound in the query, afaik the view will needed to have both types. Additional to that it seems like a bad solution for a lot of datetimes (this is just a example, I have a bunch of them in there)

Comment: You could use the [NotMapped] attribute but indeed if you have several DateTime it is not a good solution. Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions ?

Comment: Found it before, yes, but I can't understand how that fit to my problem here

Comment: a custom value conversion would help you get the date from that fancy string, although I would just modify the view to return a date.

Answer (score 0):

Like @bradbury9 is hinting to, I would change my view to

```
DATEADD(MI, wf_activate, '1899-30-12') AS Start
```

that would make Start a datetime column already when calling the database.

With the View in your Question you are first getting a datetime from the DATEADD function, then you are using CONVERT to turn it into a NVARCHAR (string).